# How save the DirectionsResult object in Google Maps

Tags: save, google-maps-api-3, routes

I want to be able to plot a route in Google Maps, modify that route by dragging it, save the changes and reload it at some later time and edit it further.  In the same manner as Google's MyMap.  Simply saving the origin and destination locations wont work as it wont reload the same route.

I can save all of the points in the via_waypoint[] array.  This allows
me to redraw the route as a polyline but it is no longer editable.

The documentation says that the DirectionsResult  is returned in JSON
format.  So I've tried to convert the DirectionsResult to a JSON
string, save and reload that string as a JSON object and pass it to
the DirectionsRenderer.  But it doesn't display and no errors are
thrown.

Below is a sample of what I was trying to do.  I've skipped the saving to the database step.  I convert the DirectionsResult to a string and then back to a JSON object.

```
   directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
       var str = JSON.stringify(response))
       var obj= JSON.parse(str)
       directionsDisplay.setDirections(obj);
     }
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should consult Google's Terms Of Use to see if this is even allowed. They are **very** restrictive on caching data.

Comment: Has anyone actually checked the ToU? @richie: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sounds like this was covered well here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657860/google-maps-saving-dragable-directions

Answer (score -1):

Why not save the coordinates of the **waypoint[]** array and reintroduce them to the a **DirectionsRequest** object's **waypoints** member? Later on, when you reload the page, make a request to the **DirectionsService** as usual, but with the previously mentioned **DirectionsRequest** object. It should be draggable if you set **draggable** to **true** in the **DirectionsRendererOptions** of your renderer.