# Google maps saving optimized directions

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I can create markers in my web application and create a route with google directions with those markers. I want the user to be able to save the directions to the database. If the user needs to open the directions, he can able to open the saved directions.

Is there any way to save the directions to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a first glance, this should be useful:

[Saving Dragable Directions Google Directions API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000473/saving-dragable-directions-google-directions-api-v3)

http://vikku.info/programming/google-maps-v3/draggable-directions/saving-draggable-directions-saving-waypoints-google-directions-google-maps-v3.htm

The second one is a complete tutorial on saving directions using AJAX, PHP and MySQL. Check it out and tell me if it's what you need.