# How to know when directionsService returns it's status?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the code below (watch error console!) I'm rapidly querying Google Maps for ten different locations to know wether it can calculate a route to there or not. This does work, but I need the result from Google to come in *before* continuing with the loop (alternating lines in the console, not like right now where my loop runs through and only then comes the status from Google).

How do I do this?

After trying this with callbacks for quite a while, I learned here [Google Maps V3 setDirections() callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228400/google-maps-v3-setdirections-callback) I probably need to do this with an event listener. So I tried searching the API Reference but could not find anything even close... but then again, I'm quite the newb so... any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?"></script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color:#FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#202020">
  <div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">


  var counter = 0;
  var destination_lat = 52.498775;
  var destination_long = 13.518474;


  do  {
    var destination_long = (destination_long + 0.2);
    var destination = destination_lat + ", " + destination_long;
    var finaldestination = destination.toString();
    calcRoute();
    console.error('longitude: ' + destination_long.toFixed (1) + ', counter: ' + counter);
    counter = (counter + 1);
  }
  while (counter < 10);


  function calcRoute() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var request = {
      origin: 'Potsdamer Platz, 10785 Berlin',
      destination: finaldestination,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT,
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      console.error('DirectionsStatus is ' + status);
    });
  }


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0):

i thougt i need an event listener but acutally geocodezip is right in his comment - i did not (and i'm pretty sure i still do not fully) understand asynchronity.

anyway, the code below works as intended - no idea wether this is a good way of doing this but it does work (only thing: i changed it slightly so it does not always make ten queries but only queries as long as there is no route and stops once there is one):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?"></script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color:#FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#202020">
  <script type="text/javascript">


  var destination_lat = 53.5219216;
  var destination_long = 13.4110207;
  var finaldestination = 'lalala';
  var valid_route = 1; // is set to 0 if route is valid, otherwise counts loops


  mainLoop();

  function mainLoop() {
    if (valid_route >= 1) {
      destination_long = (destination_long + 0.2);
      finaldestination = (destination_lat + ", " + destination_long);
      finaldestination = finaldestination.toString();
      calcRoute();
      console.error('longitude: ' + destination_long.toFixed (1) + ', loop count (valid_route): ' + valid_route);
    }
  }

  function calcRoute() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var request = {
      origin: 'Potsdamer Platz, 10785 Berlin',
      destination: finaldestination,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT,
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        valid_route = 0;
      }
      else {
        valid_route = (valid_route + 1);
      }
      console.error('DirectionsStatus is ' + status);
      mainLoop();
    });
  }


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```