# Fetching all the coordinates along a route generated by Directions Service in Google Maps Apiv3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, map-directions

My application allows a user to select two points on the map and find a route between them using the Directions Service of the Google maps Apiv3. Then the coordinates along this route has to be saved to the database. I could successfully write all the code to accomplish this. However I am left out with an issue.

I know that there are several other questions in StackOverflow- [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152160/how-to-get-the-list-of-waypoints-of-a-route-displayed-on-the-google-maps-throug), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014830/how-do-i-get-google-map-v3-direction-coordinates-from-start-to-end) on the same, but I think surely either they or me has missed out something here.

Sample Code:

```
function getCoordinates(result) {
            var currentRouteArray = result.routes[0];  //Returns a complex object containing the results of the current route
            var currentRoute = currentRouteArray.overview_path; //Returns a simplified version of all the coordinates on the path


            obj_newPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map }); //a polyline just to verify my code is fetching the coordinates
            var path = obj_newPolyline.getPath();
            for (var x = 0; x < currentRoute.length; x++) {
                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(currentRoute[x].kb, currentRoute[x].lb)
                latArray[x] = currentRoute[x].kb; //Returns the latitude
                lngArray[x] = currentRoute[x].lb; //Returns the longitude
                path.push(pos);
            }
      }
```

The above code works perfect except that the `kb` and `lb` properties of the overview path which seem to hold the lat and lng coordinates are not always the same. The last time I made the code, it was `kb` and `lb` for few days, and later it changed to `mb`, `nb` and today `jb` and `kb`.

I dont see any other properties in the object that can provide me the latlng's other than the above. Answers to other similar questions dint mention this issue. Am I missing something here? Any reliable solutions please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

do not use kb and lb which are minified names and undocumented. Use only the documented properties .lat() and .lng()

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to decode the "points" string:

```
http://home.provide.net/~bratliff/routes/
```

It is a lot faster than using the lat() / lng() methods for every individual point.