# How to enable the user of my site change the route established by the Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Sorry, if this question has been answered, but didn't find.
I use the Google Maps API on my site, but I can't change the route outlined by Google.
For example, the user establishes a starting point and an ending point; the route is traced and it included establishments (points/markers created by me). But the planned route isn't always the best for the user, who wants to drag it to the best way, and according he was dragging the route, the points of establishments were fading (those not included in the current route) and other be appearing (these included on the current route). Is this possible?
Thak you in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your `DirectionsRenderer` object, use the option `draggable:true`. Once the new route is set, recalculate your points of interest.

Related SO question: [Google maps saving draggable directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657860/google-maps-saving-dragable-directions)

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions