# Specifying saved waypoints in Google Map's Directions Service

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm running into an issue where I'm getting a `414 (Request-URI Too Large)` status back from the Google Maps API (V3), which basically means that the query string in my GET request is too long. The problem is, this GET request is automatically created by the [DirectionsService route function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), so I'm not too sure if I can do this any other way. The code in question:

```
//Setup a request object
var request = {
   origin: p1, //Point 1
   destination: p2, //Point 2
   optimizeWaypoints: true,
   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};

//If we're editing a route that has been previously saved to file
if(editing !== false){
   //Specify the waypoints
   request.waypoints = routePoints;
}

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) { 
    //Etc.
});
```

I followed this method of attaching previously-saved waypoints to the request object from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4776557/491494) on another question. Basically, `request.waypoints` is supposed to be an array of objects containing points on the map. However, on longer routes, this array can sometimes grow to 200+ points, which obviously explains the 414 code that I'm getting.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Renderign the route? Or all what you want is to plot a polyline?

Comment: @sabotero Re-render the route that was previously saved, basically.

Comment: But you what the _humman readable indications_ (if I can call that like that) or only the route on the map without this guides?

Comment: @sabotero No, the textual directions aren't really worth anything to me. Basically, the user can plot a route on the map, drag it to meet their needs and then save it. Later on, I can render the directions. However, I can't re-render any of the changes that they made by dragging the directions.

Comment: If you don't need the textual directions use Polyline

Comment: @sabotero I could, but when you're dealing with 30000+ points, it takes too long to load the Polyline. I can't render the basic waypoints because they won't snap to the road like the data found in legs[0].steps

Comment: I see. Well, I think that is way to much points. Even to do several request to DirectionsService (23 by 23 waypoints at each time). I'm suprised GoogleMaps use GET to do those queries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The maximum allowed waypoints is 8, plus the origin, and destination. Maps API for Business customers are allowed 23 waypoints, plus the origin, and destination. Waypoints are not supported for transit directions.*

[Google Maps API Reference: DirectionService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest)

Therefore you can't use `DirectionsService.route` with a request containing 200 waypoints.

Comment: Yep, I unfortunately just found this out after I started receiving a MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED status back from the Direction Service request. Of course, I had to lower my waypoints to 20, just to get a status back instead of a 414 error.