# How to get a draggable waypoint's location from google directions result

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Lokacija Partnerja</title>

  <!--stili za elemente na mapi-->
  <style type="text/css">
    html {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    /* start styles for the ContextMenu */
    
    .context_menu {
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid gray;
    }
    
    .context_menu_item {
      padding: 3px 6px;
    }
    
    .context_menu_item:hover {
      background-color: #CCCCCC;
    }
    
    .context_menu_separator {
      background-color: gray;
      height: 1px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    /* end styles for the ContextMenu */
    
    #map_container {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=quarterly&key=#YOURAPIKEY#&sensor=false"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_container'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: {
          lat: -24.345,
          lng: 134.46
        } // Australia.
      });

      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        draggable: true,
        map: map,
        panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
      });

      directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
        computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
      });

      displayRoute('Perth, WA', 'Sydney, NSW', directionsService,
        directionsDisplay);
    }

    function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {
      service.route({
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        waypoints: [{
          location: 'Adelaide, SA'
        }, {
          location: 'Broken Hill, NSW'
        }],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        avoidTolls: true
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          display.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
        }
      });
    }

    function computeTotalDistance(result) {
      var total = 0;
      var route = result.routes[0];
      for (var ij = 0; ij < route.legs[0].via_waypoints.length; ij++) {
        counter = counter + 1;
        //alert(counter + ", " + route.legs[i].via_waypoints[ij].B + ", " + route.legs[i].via_waypoints[ij].k)

        route.legs[0].via_waypoints[ij].k,
          route.legs[0].via_waypoints[ij].D
      }
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body onload="initMap()">
  <div id="map_container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to capture the location of a draggable waypoint in a google direction javascript API, so I can save it the database and load the same directions later.

I try to acces the waypoint's location via `result.routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoints[0]`, which offers me [nothing useful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRnb7.png) - `lat` and `lng` object are "empty" instead of containing geolocation (same goes for `result.routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoint[0].location`.

I have a remark in my code to access waypoint's geolocation via `result.routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoints[0].k` and `result.routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoints[0].D`, which does not work. I found on stackoverflow [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657860/google-maps-saving-draggable-directions) from 2011, which suggests to use `location.wa` and `location.ya`, which also does not work.

I've added a code snippet, you should replace `#YOURAPIKEY#` with your Google API key for the example to work. It's a slightly modified example from [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable)

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each leg of your route is a set of steps and in the case you submitted, each leg corresponds to directions between one of your stops (origin, waypoints, destination).

- `leg[0]` from Perth to Adelaide
- `leg[1]` from Adelaide to Broken Hill
- `leg[2]` from Broken Hill to Sydney

So you won't have anything in the `via_waypoints` prop.

You need to set `stopover: false` in your waypoints if you want them not considered as a real stop. Then you will get the `via_waypoints` property populated for each leg (if more than one).

```
waypoints: [{
  location: 'Adelaide, SA',
  stopover: false
}, {
  location: 'Broken Hill, NSW',
  stopover: false
}],
```

You can then iterate though `via_waypoints` and get the coordinates.

`lat` and `lng` are methods, not properties, so you need to call them, for example:

```
let firstWaypointLat = result.routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoints[0].lat();
```

Example below on how to get the waypoints coordinates:

```js
function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -24.345,
      lng: 134.46
    } // Australia.
  });

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
  });

  directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
  });

  displayRoute('Perth, WA', 'Sydney, NSW', directionsService,
    directionsDisplay);
}

function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {
  service.route({
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    waypoints: [{
      location: 'Adelaide, SA',
      stopover: false
    }, {
      location: 'Broken Hill, NSW',
      stopover: false
    }],
    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    avoidTolls: true
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      display.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function computeTotalDistance(result) {

  let leg = result.routes[0].legs[0];
  for (let i=0; i<leg.via_waypoints.length; i++) {
  
    console.log('Waypoint ' + i + ' coords: ' + leg.via_waypoints[i].lat() + ', ' + leg.via_waypoints[i].lng());
  }
}

initMap();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: You can also get `via_waypoints` by dragging one of the white circular icons on the draggable route.

Comment: As geocodezip already pointed out, `via_waypoints` are populated if you drag the suggested route on an alternative path, which is the situation I was having trouble with.
Anyway, what helped me was the hint that `lat` and `lng` are functions (which I can now also see from the debugger - I am not "native" in javascript or web development...). 
Thank you!